# Apache and XAMPP

Tags: server, apache2

I am a beginner when it comes to linux and XAMPP, and I would like to make a website using php and mySql. The problem is that I can not figure out how to make a new apache server. When I restart apache I get this message, can anybody please tell me what it means, and how to solve it?

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
[sudo] password for sheila: 
1. Restarting web server apache2
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive
globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
[fail]
2. The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the
log files to discover problems
```

Comment: `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80` is a very clear error message...

Comment: Did you made modifications on the configuration files?

Comment: AFAIK xampp uses its own installation of apache2 and has its own commands for starting and stopping it (e.g. `/opt/lampp/lampp stopapache`, `/opt/lampp/lampp startapache`) that are separate from those of the native LAMP stack. In general though you don't need to "make a new apache server" in order to make a new website.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes preloaded with Apache so the service is started automatically during boot time. If you want to use XAMPP's bundled Apache you will need to stop the current. Here are the commands:

```
sudo service apache stop
//go to /opt/lampp or whereever you've put your XAMPP and launch it
sudo ./lampp start
```

Update: if you want to start the whole XAMPP automatically during boot time (i don't recommend this since it slowers your OS), here is [how](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-start-xampp-automatically-in-ubuntu.html) (but you shoukd uninstall the current Apache so it works).